# Apply Night Mode,Classic Mode on UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an UIImage, which is captured from camera . Now my requirement is I need to apply some filters and convert that image to **Classic Mode Image,Night Mode** Image . I have been searching in the google since last 1 day finally got this [link](http://www.fiveminutes.eu/iphone-image-processing/) for the Night Mode . It is working but I think that is not night mode . Any ideas or suggestions would be very grateful . Please let me know if I am not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing all the image filtering on your own, you can use *CIFilters*. See the following links https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/QuartzCoreFramework/Classes/CIFilter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/CIFilter

For more information check out the *CoreImage* Framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `drawInRect:` to apply a blend mode to the image. A blend mode that works well for a nightmode type effect is `kCGBlendModeDifference`

for example:

```
[image drawInRect:rect blendMode:kCGBlendModeDifference alpha:1.0];
```

A list of other blend modes can be found here: [CGContext Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CGBlendMode)

You may need to play around to find one that suits your need.